# NP Problem that cannot be solved by a quantum computer in polynomial time

Tags: complexity-theory, np, cryptography, quantum-computing

1. Is there any NP-Problem that can't be (maybe even proven) solved by quantum computers. I'm not talking about quantum NP-Problems (if that's even a thing), but about normal NP.
2. If that NP Problem exists could you also use it for cryptography, since I don't want to buy a quantum computer just to be secure.

EDIT:
I'm not talking about NP-complete, because that would have no use (I think) in cryptography and also not about symmetric key encryption.

Comment: [Closely related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/); you have wrong ideas what NP-hardness means.

Comment: Yea I did, but now I think I understood it after some more research.

Comment: What is NP problem? If it NP-complete then there is no such problem known because relation between BQP and NP is currently unknown. If it is NP-hard, then recall BQP is in PSPACE so just take any problem outside of it. If it is a problem in NP and not necessary complete, then this is even stronger then unsolvability of NP-complete problem. If I remember correctly, even $BQP \in NP$ is unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nobody really knows whether quantum computers can solve all NP complete problems in polynomial time or not. There is strong evidence that they cannot: [Strengths and Weaknesses of Quantum Computing](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9701001), but no definite proof.