# Trapdoor functions that depends only on NP-hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

As far as I can tell, there are no examples of trapdoor functions which hardness assumptions is merely hardness of some NP-hard problem in worst case. That is, a trapdoor function in which, it is proved that, if there is an PPT algorithm that can invert it with non-negligible probability, then there is a PT algorithm which can solve the worst case of some NP-hard problem.

If I am wrong on the above, can you show me an example of such function?

If I am not, why is it so hard to make such a trapdoor function? Is there a concrete reason why it's hard to develop such function (beside "we haven't figure it out yet")?

This supposedly "duplicate" question ([Why hasn't there been an encryption algorithm that is based on the known NP-Hard problems?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/why-hasnt-there-been-an-encryption-algorithm-that-is-based-on-the-known-np-hard)) doesn't actually answer this question. That question isn't why worst case NP-hard isn't enough to make an encryption out of it. This question is essentially about why there had been no successful attempt at reducing average-case hardness down to worst-case NP-hard, for the purpose of making trapdoor function. There had been problems where average-case is just as hard as worst-case, so the fact that not all problems has worst-case=average-case doesn't mean you can't use different problems where that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of the problem lies in worst to average case reductions. The standard construction of a function which is average case hard is taking a function which is worst case hard and applying all kinds of fancy error correcting codes on its truth table. See Ta-Shma's [notes](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Eamnon/Classes/2017-BPP/Lectures/Lecture3b.pdf) sketching the STV construction. As far as I know, we don't know how to do that for NP (STV starts with a PSPACE hard function).

Even worse, we believe this can't be done for NP. See [Bogdanov Trevisan](https://lucatrevisan.github.io/pubs/redux-sicomp.pdf), where it is shown that if an NP complete problem has a worst to average case reduction then the hierarchy collapses. Your problem is not exactly worst to average case reduction, but reducing an NP hard problem to inverting a one way function. However, these are related and Trevisan's paper also rules out such non-adaptive reductions.

More directly related to your question is [AGGM](http://people.csail.mit.edu/akavia/AGGM.pdf), which also rules out adaptive reductions for the case where the size of the inverse image is easy to compute. You might also want to check out this [paper](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Eamnon/Papers/GT.Random07.pdf). These results are 10-15 years old (STV is around 20), I have no idea if anything stronger was proven since.

Comment: Thanks! This has everything I looked for.